# OnePlus3 Nougat: TelephonyManager getNetworkType() returning value 19 instead of 13

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-7.0-nougat, oneplusthree

OnePlus3 Nougat only (so far): TelephonyManager getNetworkType() is sometimes (!?) returning the value `19` which is not defined in the doc, according the the situation it should be `NETWORK_TYPE_LTE = 13` as the status bar is showing 4G+.
Obviously users are down-rating my app again, instead of blaming OnePlus.

Any Idea What is going on with the OnePlus3?
Why is the Status Bar working fine?
Is that supposed to be official?
I'll add this 19 as a hard-coded value for LTE but what if it changes in the future... My app will be wrong for real.
And more generally, How can I avoid users to blame me for all the Android/Manufacturer bugs that are introduced in every new release?

Doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType()

System Data:
VERSION.RELEASE{7.0},VERSION.INCREMENTAL{97},VERSION.SDK{24},BOARD{QC_Reference_Phone},BRAND{OnePlus},DEVICE{OnePlus3},FINGERPRINT{OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3:7.0/NRD90M/12311011:user/release-keys},HOST{ubuntu-23},ID{NRD90M}

Comment: "Why is the Status Bar working fine?" -- presumably, they changed it to match. "Is that supposed to be official?" -- that depends on your definition of "official". Presumably, OnePlus considers it to be official, as it is what they are shipping. "How can I avoid users to blame me for all the Android/Manufacturer bugs that are introduced in every new release?" -- do not ship apps to users who are in position to cast blame, particularly apps that are especially sensitive to variations in hardware. Or, live with the complaints, fixing them where you can.

Comment: Thx! I guess you are unfortunately right, this are the answers I didn't want to believe in. I am amazed how they would change their UI instead of fixing the origin... :'(

Comment: Ideally, Google's Compatibility Test Suite would cover this. Apparently, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

4G+ is the new LTE-Advanced (LTE-A) and doesn't exist as constant in TelephonyManager class.

4G is LTE (NETWORK_TYPE_LTE = 13).

I hope Google will update its constants or give us the value for 4G+ (19 ?).